# Symfony 4.4 unable to set custom service visibility to public

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having a really weird issue that seems to go against the documentation.

For the sake of my unit tests, I'm trying to set a specific service visibility to 'public'. But that does not work at all.

```
# config/services.yaml

services:
  # default configuration for services in *this* file
  _defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.  

  App\Service\Common\TokenService:
    public: true
```

But I still get this error in my test when I try to mock it :

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
> : The "App\Service\Common\TokenService" service is private, you cannot
> replace it.

When I run this command `php bin/console debug:container TokenService` I get the following :

```
---------------- ---------------------------------
  Option           Value                           
 ---------------- ---------------------------------
  Service ID       App\Service\Common\TokenService
  Class            App\Service\Common\TokenService
  Tags             -
  Public           no <==== WHY ?
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        yes
  Autoconfigured   yes
```

If I set "public: true" below _defaults it works, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here is, that the order of the services counts.

Your config will create your service and makes it public, but later on you have some lines like this:

```yaml
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migration,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

The service will be created again and overwrite your previous declaration and make it non public again.

Just put your config after this line.